# Oracle Average Query

Tags: sql, oracle, average

One would think this would be simple.  I just want the date, count & average per day for whatever time range.  So, in the example below, I want the count & average per day over the 10 day period.

```
SELECT date_added, 10 / customer_cnt AS average
FROM (SELECT TRUNC(date_added) AS date_added, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(date_added) ORDER BY TRUNC(date_added)) AS  rnum,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(date_added)) AS customer_cnt
     FROM payments_log
     WHERE action = 'get_cc_info'
       AND TRUNC(date_added) >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 10)
WHERE rnum = 1;
```

But I'm not getting anything close to what I expect.

Comment: Please provide sample data and edesired results.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what "average per day" means.  I think you just want the count:

```
SELECT TRUNC(date_added) AS date_added, 
        COUNT(*) as day_count
FROM payments_log
WHERE action = 'get_cc_info' AND
      date_added >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '10' day
GROUP BY TRUNC(date_added);
```

If you want the average during this period (i.e. *one* row in the result set), then you want something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / 10 as daily_average
       COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT TRUNC(date_added) daily_average_on_days_with_data
FROM payments_log
WHERE action = 'get_cc_info' AND
      date_added >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '10' day;
```

Comment: Not one row, but the average per day, based on the 10 days........